# Upload file to ColdFusion with Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, coldfusion

I have an Ionic app that sends an image to a server, the script to handle the file upload is written in ColdFusion and written by someone else, I'm not a ColdFusion developer. Here is what he wrote:

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/app">

<cffunction name="testpostpics" access="remote" returntype="any" produces="application/json" httpmethod="POST" restpath="/testpics">
    <cfargument name="file" required="false" type="any" restArgSource="form" />
    <cfset var aStruct = {}>
    <cfset var pics="https://www.example.com/members/pics/">

    <cftry>
        <cffile action="upload" filefield="file" nameconflict="makeunique" destination="#picpath#" result="result">

        <cfcatch type="any">
            <cfset var aStruct = { success = 0, error = "#cfcatch.message#", details = "#cfcatch.Detail#" }>
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>``

    <cfif StructIsEmpty(aStruct)>
        <cfset var aStruct = { success = 1, pic = "#pics##result.ServerFile#" }>
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn serializeJSON(aStruct)>
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

When I try to upload the image, the response is empty, it doesn't throw an error, it's just empty. Here is a sample response

```
{"bytesSent":15703,"responseCode":204,"response":"","objectId":""}
```

My Ionic code:

```
let options = {
    fileKey: "file",
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data"
};
fileTransfer.upload(imageFile,'url', options, true).then(resp => {
    console.log("resp"+ JSON.stringify(resp));
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log("RespError" + JSON.stringify(err));
})
```

This works well with a PHP script but not with ColdFusion. Is anything wrong with that ColdFusion code?

Comment: 204 isn't an error, it's a status code that basically says you should expect an empty response. so...

Comment: Start by testing if the function is even being called. If it is, then monitor the value of `aStruct` before the return occurs.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that ColdFusion code. That response is coming from something else. The code you have posted is not sending that response.